# "ŞÜÖ" is 6 characters long

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: utf-8
str='ŞÜÖ'
a = len(str)
print str
print a
```

the output is:

```
ŞÜÖ
6
```

first question is: how to get it to show me 6 characters that it claims..

and second question is..

is it possible to ensure python can see these as "1" character for each character in other words 3 total for the above example ?

Comment: `how to get it to show me 6 characters that it claims`: `for char in str: print(char)`

Comment: For your second question, use unicode strings instead of normal strings (i.e. str=u'ŞÜÖ', then len(str) -> 3).

Answer (score 8):

In Python2, a `str` is a sequence of bytes. This string is composed of 6 bytes:

```
In [136]: text = 'ŞÜÖ'

In [137]: list(text)
Out[137]: ['\xc5', '\x9e', '\xc3', '\x9c', '\xc3', '\x96']
```

If you decode the `str` to make a `unicode`:

```
In [138]: unitext = text.decode('utf-8')
```

Then the `unitext` is composed of 3 unicode characters:

```
In [139]: len(unitext)
Out[139]: 3

In [140]: list(unitext)
Out[140]: [u'\u015e', u'\xdc', u'\xd6']
```

Comment: Or just use a `unicode` literal in the first place: `u'ŞÜÖ'`